# Unable to execute command dnx web

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, kestrel-http-server, asp.net5

For some reason I'm not able to run a simple, out of the box ASP.NET 5 / Core 1.0 web app with DNX and Kestrel. After running `dnx web` I keep getting the error:

`Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel'. Available commands: web, ef.`

My project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-WebApplication-635604fe-13b8-4779-8e12-35ec067b73ae",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "WebApplication"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Sqlite": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime":"1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "bower install",
      "gulp clean",
      "gulp min"
    ]
  }
}
```

Yes, I have run `dnu restore` before. I have these runtimes installed:

```
dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1
dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update2
dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1
dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2
dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update2
```

I really hope someone knows where this issue might come from.

**UPDATE**

It appears that i have an issue with resolving dependencies and assembly bindings. Whenever i run `dnu build` it builds just fine and i can see that all nuget package dependencies are resolved/restored in C:\users\*****\.dnx\packages.

However, when running `dnx web`, I keep getting the error i mentioned. I enabled the FusionLog and it seems that the earlier nuget package dependencies are now not resolved. I keep getting errors like this:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at WebApplication.Startup.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteMain>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Users\*****\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2\bin\dnx.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/*****/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file:
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
LOG: Fusion is hosted. Check host about this assembly.
LOG: Try host assembly store with assembly microsoft.aspnet.hosting, version=1.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=adb9793829ddae60, processorarchitecture=x86.
LOG: Try host assembly store with assembly microsoft.aspnet.hosting, version=1.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=adb9793829ddae60, processorarchitecture=msil.
LOG: Try host assembly store with assembly microsoft.aspnet.hosting, version=1.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=adb9793829ddae60.
WRN: Host assembly store does not contain this assembly.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/*****/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2/bin/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/*****/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2/bin/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/*****/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2/bin/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/*****/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2/bin/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.EXE.
```

So I now know where the problem lies. If i temporarily copy the required dlls to `/C:/Users/*****/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2/bin` it seems to resolve fine, though this is not a solution.

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that the issue is the clr runtime. Whenever i use the coreclr by entering the cmd `dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -a x86 -r coreclr` followed by `dnx web`, the app runs just fine.

I've tried reinstalling the clr, installing both update1 and update2 for both x64 and x86, but the error remains. Only the coreclr seems to work. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Are you running the commands from within your projects directory?

Comment: I forgot to mention the obvious, but yes. Thanks for thinking with me.

Comment: What happens if you run `dnx Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting hosting.ini`?

Comment: Then i get almost the same error: `Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'. Available commands: web, ef.`

Comment: Do you have a global.json?

Comment: nope. No global.json. It is a system wide issue. I have it with all ASP.Net 5 apps, even empty/newly generated.

Comment: Which framework does `dnvm list` say is currently active?

Comment: *    1.0.0-rc1-update2 clr     x86          win             default

Comment: DNX is deprecated, .NET Core CLI should be used, so voting  to close as a problem, that cannot be reproduced.